# Deploying React App to Git Hub Pages failed

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, create-react-app

I am trying to deploy my react app to github pages............

Followed a tutorial and managed to make it work for a previous project.
When i run npm run deploy I am getting this error
Any help would be appreciated how to interpret this error
I tried different solutions found here but none helped

npm run deploy

```js
> Neighbourhood-Map-React@0.1.0 predeploy C:\Users\mels_\Documents\Neighbourhood-Map-React
> npm run build


> Neighbourhood-Map-React@0.1.0 build C:\Users\mels_\Documents\Neighbourhood-Map-React
> react-scripts build

   Creating an optimized production build...
   Failed to compile.

   Error: Parse Error: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial  
     -scale=1>
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
      <!--
        manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
        homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamental  
      s/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
      -->
      <link rel="manifest" href="/github.io/Neighbourhood-Map-React/manifest.jso  n">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/github.io/Neighbourhood-Map-React/favicon  .ico">
      <!--
        Notice the use of /github.io/Neighbourhood-Map-React in the tags above.
        It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build  .
        Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.
        Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/github.io/Neighbourhood-Map-Re  act/favicon.ico" will
        work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
        Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.      -->
      <title>React App</title>
    <link href="/github.io/Neighbourhood-Map-React/static/css/main.c066d278.css"   rel="stylesheet"></head>
    <body>
      <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
      </noscript>
      <div id="root"></div>
      <!--
        This HTML file is a template.
        If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.
        You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
        The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.
        To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
        To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
      -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/github.io/Neighbourhood-Map-React/stati  c/js/main.df359430.js"></script></body>
  </html>

  - htmlparser.js:240 new HTMLParser
    [Neighbourhood-Map-React]/[html-minifier]/src/htmlparser.js:240:13

  - htmlminifier.js:951 minify
    [Neighbourhood-Map-React]/[html-minifier]/src/htmlminifier.js:951:3

  - htmlminifier.js:1306 exports.minify
    [Neighbourhood-Map-React]/[html-minifier]/src/htmlminifier.js:1306:16

  - index.js:296
    [Neighbourhood-Map-React]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:296:16

  - util.js:16 tryCatcher
    [Neighbourhood-Map-React]/[bluebird]/js/release/util.js:16:23

  - promise.js:512 Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
    [Neighbourhood-Map-React]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:512:31

  - promise.js:569 Promise._settlePromise
    [Neighbourhood-Map-React]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:569:18

  - promise.js:614 Promise._settlePromise0
    [Neighbourhood-Map-React]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:614:10

  - promise.js:693 Promise._settlePromises
    [Neighbourhood-Map-React]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:693:18

  - async.js:133 Async._drainQueue
    [Neighbourhood-Map-React]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:133:16

  - async.js:143 Async._drainQueues
    [Neighbourhood-Map-React]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:143:10

  - async.js:17 Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate]
    [Neighbourhood-Map-React]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:17:14


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Neighbourhood-Map-React@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Neighbourhood-Map-React@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mels_\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-20T13_00_54_457Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Neighbourhood-Map-React@0.1.0 predeploy: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Neighbourhood-Map-React@0.1.0 predeploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mels_\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-20T13_00_54_550Z-debug.log
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in package-lock.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

Comment: Seems like you forgot " after  initial-scale=1, should be <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Orkhan Jafarov pointed out, Your script failed on parsing error. You are missing `"` at the end of your `meta` tag.

```
   Error: Parse Error: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1>
```

Comment: oooppsss i feel embarrassed now It took me a whole day of different tries.I did not checked that part as local host worked so i assumed the issue is somewhere else.Thank you for the help and time.It is much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

There are a few common errors when using HTTPS with Git. These errors usually indicate you have an old version of Git, or you don't have access to the repository.
When prompted for a username and password, make sure you use an account that has access to the repository.

With Git for Windows, running the following in the command line will store your credentials:

```
$ git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

this is called as turning on password caching